# Gitlab call group and Project together using bash

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab

I have a text file already that contain project id and project_names. But a request has been made to call together both group and project together in the same curl.

How can I call group and project id together and how would I modify the text file (config.txt) that contain the projectid and projectnames to contain the groupid?

```
config.txt
324566 projectnames1 projecttypes1
333456 projectnames2 projecttypes2


IN_FILE='./config.txt'

if [ -f "$IN_FILE" ]; then
    echo "$IN_FILE exists and the operation can continue"



while read -ra LINE
do
        a="${LINE[0]}"; b="${LINE[1]}"; c="${LINE[2]}"

               echo "$a"
               echo "$b"
               echo "$c"
projectid=$a
projectnames=$b
projecttypes=$c
mkdir ./archive_$projectid-$projectnames

sudo chmod -R 755  /Users/names/git/archive_$projectid-$projectnames



curlfile=$(curl -s -I --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:xxxxxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$projectid/variables" | grep HTTP/ | awk {'print $2'})

echo "$curlfile"
### This will check if status response is between 200 -299 inclusive
if (( $curlfile >= 200 && $curlfile <= 300 )) ; then
    echo "$curlfile exists and the operation can start processing"

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:xxxxxxxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$projectid/variables" | python3 -m json.tool  > $projectid-$projectnames.json
 # echo "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$projectid/variables"
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean exactly by "call together"?

Comment: I meant to call the groupid and project id in the same line like this curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:xxxxxxxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/{groupid}//variables/{projectid}"

Comment: You can't modify multiple projects in a single request, if that's what you want to do. You have to call the projects endpoint for each project.

Comment: @sytech. Thanks. Is there a way to put group and project in text file and identify which group is linked to project id and call it?